# Find the area of the surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

The part of the plane $$x+2y+3z=1$$ that lies inside the cylinder $$x^2+y^2=3$$.
This is how I have started solving the problem: $$S=\int\int_{D}\sqrt{1+\left({\partial z\over \partial x}\right)^2+\left({\partial z\over \partial y}\right)^2}dA$$
$$S=\int\int_D \sqrt{1+\left(\frac13\right)^2+\left(\frac23\right)^2}dA$$  $$S=\int\int_D {\sqrt{14}\over3}dA$$
This is where my question comes in. Should I convert to polar coordinates? If so, how would I find what my limits of integration are. If no, why and how would I find the limits of integration? If someone could help me out, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates:

$$\begin{align}
x&=r\cos\theta \\
y&=r\sin\theta \\
dA&=r\,dr\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

You're integration over the full area of a circle of radius $\sqrt{3}$, so the limits of integration are

$$\begin{align}
0&\le{\theta}<2\pi \\
0&\le{r}<\sqrt{3}
\end{align}$$